# Problema con el formulario xml

Tags: android-studio

Esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, he aquí molestando nuevamente, salgo de una y entro en otra.
Les comento que avance harto en mi proyecto, como cuatro formularios más y cuando quise volver hacia atrás y ver el primer formulario realizado me encontré con la siguiente sorpresa:

[image: Formulario del frmcasos (xml-diseño)]

El error es:

> Touch Target size too small

[image: la segunda con los errores]

y todos los formularios están igual que este, no sé cuál es el error que lo ocasiono y como solucionarlo, busque alguna solución en la web y no encontré nada, favor de ayudarme en este pequeño problema, ya que al ejecutarlo todos los `edittext` y los `buttons` se ven chicos, antes estaba bien y empezó cuando actualice una librería, disculpen las  molestias y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Agrega activity_frmcasos1.xml  por favor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error:

> Touch Target size too small

indica que **estás haciendo uso de vistas (EditText, Buttons, ImageView, etc), cuya medida es menor a 48 pixeles, estas vistas pequeñas pueden ser difíciles de hacer clic o tocar**, como lo puedes ver en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo ideal es que tus botones en este caso tengan medida mayor a 48 pixeles de alto, lo cual es recomendado en Android (en [Web lo recomendado son 44px](https://licreativetechnologies.com/seo/how-important-is-size-tap-targets-appropriately-to-seo/)), de otra forma tendrás este error.